# The two-dotted i: the "i" disappears

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I need to type the word "naïve" in plain text in Latex. Things that I've tried:
`na\"{\i}ve, na{\"{\i}}ve, na\"\i ve`, and other combinations of brackets: i dissappears, and this is what I get: [image: naïve result]

I tried to switch to math mode and then it works, but I cannot make the `\imath` to look non-italic, this is what I get from `$\mathrm{na\ddot{\imath}ve}$` :

[image: math mode]

EDIT: Added minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
% bibentry workaround
\makeatletter
\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem
\makeatother
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{calc}           % berekeningen voor paginagrootte
\usepackage{afterpage}      % om een \clearpage na einde van pagina te zetten
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[pdftex=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,hidelinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfauthor={...},
    pdftitle={...},
    pdfsubject={...}
}

\usepackage[english,tight]{minitoc}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{2}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg, .jpeg, .png}
\graphicspath{{../images/}{images/}}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=small]{caption}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{margin=4pt}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
    flexiblecolumns=true,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    basewidth=0.4em,
    aboveskip=5mm,
    belowskip=2mm,
    frame=tb,
    frameround=fttt,
    framexleftmargin=2mm,
    framexrightmargin=2mm,
    framextopmargin=1mm,
    framexbottommargin=1mm,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    mathescape,
    captionpos=b
}

\lstdefinelanguage{XML}{
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[s]{>}{<},
    morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    identifierstyle=\color{blue},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    morekeywords={role,content,action,level}
}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\usepackage[square,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

%
% new/renew commands
%
\renewcommand{\mtcfont}{\small\rm}
\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\small\bf}
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\citep{#1}}
\renewcommand{\i}[1]{#1\index{#1}}

%
% make appropriate UHasselt style
%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large} 
{\filright{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{4ex}
{\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filcenter}
[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]

\setlength\oddsidemargin{4cm - 1in}
\setlength\evensidemargin{4cm - 1in}
\setlength\textwidth{13cm}

\setlength\topmargin{48mm - 1in}
\setlength\headheight{26pt}
\setlength\headsep{10pt}
\setlength\textheight{20cm - \headheight - \headsep}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}{}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\cfoot{}

%
% custom stuff
%
\vfuzz=2pt % don't report over-full v-boxes if over-edge is small
\hfuzz=2pt % don't report over-full h-boxes if over-edge is small

%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\@addtoreset{section}{part}
%\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}

%
% prepare things...
%
\def\C++{\leavevmode{\hbox{C\hskip -0.1ex\raise 0.5ex\hbox{\tiny ++}}}} % nice C++ logo
\def\Csharp{\leavevmode{\hbox{C\hskip -0.1ex\raise 0.5ex\hbox{\tiny \#}}}} % nice C# logo

\makeindex
\dominitoc

\begin{document}
    na\"{\i}ve
\end{document}
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: `na\"ive` works for me. No need to escape the `i`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Switching to math mode is not really the right solution. ï works as well in unicode

Comment: \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Either type ALT 00EF for ï: naïve

or use \"i: na\"ive


\end{document}

Comment: The definition of `\i` as the `lazy LaTeX-User` form for `\index` seems to be the cause of the issue

Comment: Redefining `\i` is the obvious problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian! The large code block came as a template. If I comment the line, it works :)

Comment: @aspsnake: Although seducing in 99.9% of all cases such short track commands with `\i` etc. bite you in the long end and leave the code hard to track and read. I don't recommend to use them.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yeah, I don't. This huge block before the document came as a template for a thesis text from the university, so I didn't even look at it.

Comment: @aspsnake: Quick, get out of that university if they provide such rubbish templates ;-)

Comment: Still curious why you were using `\"\i` in the first place, rather than `\"i`. I understand that in some sense one may think one is placing the diaeresis over a dotless i rather than over i, but the font designer has already arranged things to account for this so why try to do it "manually"?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I was googling and found and old answer where a person was getting 3 dots over i with just \"i, and was recommended to use \"\i. But maybe it was true for older versions of Latex. I already switched to \"i in my text.

Comment: @aspsnake Actually you are right, after reading Heiko's answer and experimenting myself, I do see that with "default" plain TeX, `\"\i` gives the wrong output.

Comment: Ah I understand now: in `plain.tex`, we have `\"` defined as `\def\"#1{{\accent"7F #1}}`, but in LaTeX `\"` is defined differently (`\show` gives `\OT1-cmd \"\OT1\"` but I'm not sure where this comes from). So in plain TeX one indeed needs to use `\"\i`, but not in (at least the present version of) LaTeX

Answer (score 2):

## Update for question with MWE ([version 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/375089/3))

The `OT1` encoding composes the ï with the accent (`\"`) and the dotless i (`\i`), because there is no slot available in the 7-bit font encoding.
The `T1` encoding has slot 239 for this glyph (from `t1enc.def`):

```
\DeclareTextComposite{\"}{T1}{i}{239}
\DeclareTextComposite{\"}{T1}{\i}{239}
```

Therefore the form `\"i` works without an explicit or implicit `\i`, thus that
`\i` can even be redefined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\i}[1]{#1\index{#1}}
\begin{document}
na\"ive
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Older version

<sup>Wild guess, based on [version 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/375089/2) of the question without
[minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).</sup>

The accent command `\"` is a text command that causes an error in math mode (your question is tagged with [math-mode](/questions/tagged/math-mode)). Switch to text mode to typeset the word, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}% or amsmath, provides \text
\begin{document}
\[ \mbox{na\"ive} = \text{na\"ive} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `\i` as the lazy LaTeX-User form for `\index` seems to be the cause of the issue – Christian Hupfer.

Commenting the line `\renewcommand{\i}[1]{#1\index{#1}}` fixed the problem.

Thanks!!

Comment: It would have been a nice gesture to ask Christian to answer the question and then accept and upvote instead to answer yourself.

Comment: @TeXnician The answer answers the question. The *additional* thanking does not change that and is therefore *not* a reason for closing.

Comment: I have upvoted to cancel out the downvote. This does indeed answer the question (though I also agree it would have been better to get Christian to answer it… but we shouldn't expect new users to follow norms that aren't even clear to established users. The fact that the OP posted the answer in the answer section is itself a good thing).

Comment: @moewe: It's alright...

Comment: @moewe I do not know, why people answers questions in comments, rather writing real answers. This keeps the question in the list of unanswered questions. Therefore, the OP is right to answer the question with the reference to the finder of the problem cause.

Comment: I'm happy if Christian answers it, I will delete this post then. But he answered it in a comment...

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Well, I sometimes suggest a solution in the comments and wait for the OP to respond whether it helped or not. Only if it was the solution for the OP, I proceed to write an answer. I'm not sure if people actually voted on this question - it was in an automatic review queue. I didn't vote for deletion, since the answer clearly answers the question. I just wanted to let the poster know that it is a nice gesture to let the person that gave the answer write an answer.

Comment: @moewe I do not see a reason for posting the answer as comment here, because the reason for the problem is quite trivial and does not need further clarification by the author. There is even a full example that could be used for checking the answer.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Well, obviously I can't speak for Christian here. I simply explained why I answer in comments sometimes.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: moewe's reasoning is the same as mine here: My comment was a `not - yet - an - answer -and-wait-for-response-comment`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't see what are we discussing here :) if you just copy - paste your comment into an answer, I will mark it as the one that answered my question ;)

Comment: @aspsnake: It's not really important to discuss about it anyway... keep your answer.